# Помогите пожалуйста с вёрсткой навигационной панели слайдера

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, slick.js

Использую slick slider. При выборе слайда или просто прокрутке в секции миниатюр, почему то забрасывает блок с слайдами очень далеко, не могу понять почему, ширина ж вроди как регулируется по кол-ву слайдов. 
JS

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('.cool-slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  autoplay: false,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.cool-slider-nav',
  nextArrow: '<a class="right carousel-control custom-ico-slide"><i class="demo-icon icon-right-open-big" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
  prevArrow: '<a class="left carousel-control custom-ico-slide"><i class="demo-icon icon-left-open-big" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
  fade: true
})

$('.cool-slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: false,
  asNavFor: '.cool-slider',
  focusOnSelect: true,
  infinite : false,
  arrows: false,
  dots: true,
  appendDots: $(".caption-wrapper")
}); 
});
```

Проблему с слайдером оставляю по ссылке. Код html и сss сбрасывать не буду. Укажите пожалуйста в чем моя ошибка
http://blackfoxrealty.com/agents/john-johnson/

Answer (score 0):

При том варианте, который у вас сейчас `cool-slider-nav` вам не нужен слайдер. У вас все 6 слайдов умещаются на одном экране. И поэтому данные слайды служат как кастомные `dots`, но точно не слайдер. Увеличьте их ширину в два раза и увидите нормальный результат.